# SVG ViewBox To Width and Height

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

i really cannot understand how viewBox works i read alot about it but i want to know how can i make sure it fit the outer container like this example :

```
<div class="container">
<svg viewBox="0 0 100% 100vh">
<rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="1200" height="800" fill="#19dddd"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

css :

```
.container{
width :100%;
height:100vh;
}

.container svg{
width:100%;
height:100%
}
```

can someone explain how can i make it fit inside the container to take its full width and height ?

Comment: Do you want the graphic to stretch and distort to fill the available space? Or do you want to cover the available space without stretching/distorting the graphic?

Answer (score 2):

You must specify viewBox parameters without dimension units

`viewBox="0 0 1200 800"`

In order for the svg to completely fill the parent container, you need to delete the width and height of the svg or specify how you have done the width and height equal to 100%

```css
.container{
width :100vw;
height:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg viewBox="0 0 1200 800">
<rect  width="100%" height="100%" fill="#19dddd"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: it works with the width but its height still overflows the container when i specify overflow:hidden; it crops the background :(

Comment: @JhonDonald Changed styles for parent container

Comment: its height got fixed but the width still not 100% , also when i shrink screen its width and height goes smaller than the container

Comment: @Jhon Donald Replaced rectangle attributes with 100% width and height

Comment: still wont work , i guess there is something with javascript that change viewBox to fix the issue

Comment: @Jhon Donald Apparently your further layout breaks something. With this code, everything works. Only you can solve problems with layout

Comment: thank you Alexandr_TT for trying to help , i will try to find a solution and post it here :)

Answer (score 0):

[MDN Web Docs' viewBox documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) has a straightforward explanation - inside the viewbox there are 4 numbers that you must modify for the min/max and default sizes. Yours probably isn't working because you've added % and vh parameteres; it only accepts numbers.

So you would be better off entering the size of the svg in number units.

Answer (score 0):

It works when you display css proterties ( width and height ) by 100% , then add preserveAspectRatio="none" to your svg .

my viewBox="0 0 750 500".